# Valet Stopped Working after macOS High Sierra Upgrade from macOS Sierra

Tags: nginx, macos-high-sierra, dnsmasq, laravel-valet

Upgrading the macOS from Sierra to High Sierra breaks working Valet installation. Ping works just fine, it is just *.dev on browser gives error that unable to connect, site cannot be connected.

I have tried usual troubleshooting steps like Uninstalling Valet and installing again but same issue.

I read somewhere it was related DNSMasq so i have unlinked and uninstalled it many times via brew with no success.

Anyone has faced this issue and any suggested fixes?

Comment: do let us know if you fix the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: I got it fixed finally. It was related to DNSmasq as originally suspected, however it did not matter how many times I removed and re installed dnsmasq via Brew.

So here is what worked for me:

1. Removed dnsmasq `brew uninstall dnsmasq` had it done many times but this time, did next step which helped.
2. Remove dnsmasq's config files and any dnsmasq directory in  `/usr/local/etc` (**this step is what fixed my issue**)
3. Now reinstall Valet, `valet install` it will install missing dnsmasq itself and new config of dnsmasq will work just fine as it worked in my case.

Hope it works for you also.

PS. Also I removed whole Valet and reinstalled Valet after removing old valet directory settings in home directory i.e. removed `~/.valet` and then installed Valet again.

Comment: Hours wasted on this, thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I came across this answer having experienced the same problem, however DNSmasq was not the problem for my Valet. I fixed the same symptoms by following the below steps.

**Step 1**
Uninstalled and reinstalled valet to v2

1. `valet stop`
2. `valet uninstall`
3. `composer global require laravel/valet` - assuming this is how you installed it.
4. `valet install`
5. `valet restart`

This did not entirely fix the problem. But the browser then gives

> secure connection could not be made

Which leads on to step 2.

**Step 2**
Having read this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/434) on Google enforcing HTTPS on the `.dev` domain name it turned out that simply running `valet secure [name of app]` allowed it work again.

Alternatively, if you don't want to do this for lots of apps, or specifically want to run as HTTP, then running `valet domain localhost` will update your Valet sites to use `.localhost` instead. Localhost is a reserved word and therefore should not be subject to the same problem later on.

Comment: This help me after upgrade macos to Big Sur. I do only first step and done

Answer (score 0):

I did, valet domain localhost and could open http://mysite.localhost in browser without any further problems

Answer (score 0):

I run into this almost every time after MacOS updates.

Running `valet install` normally does the trick for me.

To avoid other common issues:

1. Accept the new TOC
2. Update Xcode